# Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I got the the  MissingMethodException while using "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.0" and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" on net6.0.

Is it a known issue or do you see any problem with my csproj file?

```
 Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IndexBuilder Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasIndex(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!0,System.Object>>)'.

21:02:29 [Error] () [null]

21:02:30 [Error] ()    at QA.Portal.DAL.QAPortalContext.QAPortalContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.1" />
      
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" Version="6.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.1" />
      
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.MySqlStorage" Version="2.0.3" />
      
    <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp" Version="5.5.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This link help you for resolve your issue:-https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8467

Comment: It is likely that either one of your projects or one of your packages expects an older version of EF Core. Is your context inheriting from a base class different than `DbContext` or is the class maybe located in a different project that still references an older version?

Comment: @lauxjpn Yes, it's the case. I upgraded from .netcore2.2 to 5.0 without touching other packages so I forgot about that. It works now. Thanks you!